# Difference between register indirect and base plus offset in MIPS addressing mode?

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips, addressing-mode

What is the difference between *register indirect* and *base plus offset*, and how does it affect how you write assembly on the MIPS architecture? I think it means that you can only reference the register in an instruction, and that register has to point to more instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Register indirect" addressing means that the address which will be used by the
instruction (known as the "effective address") is taken from the contents of a
register, rather than being encoded directly within the instruction itself
(which is "absolute" addressing).  MIPS has jump instructions for both of these
addressing modes:

```
j 0x1234
```

means "jump to address `0x1234`" (absolute addressing), whereas

```
jr $ra
```

means "jump to the address contained in the `$ra` register" (register indirect
addressing).

"Base plus offset" addressing means that a base address is taken from the
contents of a register, and then an offset (which is encoded in the instruction
itself) is added.  MIPS uses this addressing mode for loads and stores.  For
example:

```
lw $t0, 0($a0)
lw $t1, 4($a0)
```

...if `$a0` contains `0x1234`, then `$t0` will be loaded with the word at
address `0x1234` (the effective address is the contents of the register, plus
an offset of 0), and `$t1` will be loaded with the word at address `0x1238`
(the effective address is the contents of the register, plus an offset of 4).

As you can see, when the offset is 0, this is equivalent to register indirect
addressing.

Comment: So what would be the equivalent in "Register Indirect" if there was an offset other then 0?

Comment: Register indirect is less flexible, because it only does half as much as base+offset.  But you could add the offset yourself, e.g. `addiu $ra, $ra, 4 ; jr $ra`.

Comment: So the offset makes it possible to refer to memory that is close to `$ra` but moved over 4 bits? I'm just trying to get these concepts down :) Thanks!

Comment: If you have the address of some code in a register, it's probably either the address of a routine you want to call, or the address of some code you want to return to.  Either way, although you *could* add an offset to that address, it's rarely useful to do so, which perhaps explains why `jr` provides only register indirect addressing.  Accessing data is a different matter: it's very common to want to find data at a fixed small offset from a given base address.

Answer (score 3):

Register indirect addressing mode is just a special case of base plus offset addressing mode when offset is zero.

The base plus offset addressing mode is used when you have a structure with multiple data items and want to refer to the items. The base register points to the beginning of the structure and offset is used to extract a particular item. Example is loading an address of a virtual method where base register points to the base of the virtual method table and an offset indicates the method of interest. Another example is referring to function's local variables on the stack where base register points to the stack frame of the function and offset indicates the particular variable of interest.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the same instruction but for both modes, in assembly?

Comment: Base plus offset: `sw $s0, 4($sp)`, register indirect: `sw $s1, 0($sp)`.